# Using dpkg for package info

Tags: debian, package-management, dpkg, deb

I'm trying to use `dpkg` tool to list which packages are installed on my machine. Using the `-l` option it reports "un" for some packages which means unknown, "not-installed". Does "not-installed" flag means that there is such a package, it is available for the system I'm running at but it's not present on my machine (locally) and I have to download the `.deb` file from the web and install it?

Answer (score 1):

I’ll address the underlying question first:

```
dpkg -l | grep '^.i'
```

will list all installed packages. Other tools can provide this information too; for example

```
apt list --installed
```

In `dpkg -l`’s output, “not-installed” does indeed mean that `dpkg` is aware of a package’s existence, even though it’s not installed on your system. The package file itself might be available on your system, for example in the APT cache in `/var/cache/apt/archives`, but `dpkg`’s doesn’t know that. From `dpkg`’s perspective, as you say, you’d have to download the package file, or obtain it in some other way, and install it.

Answer (score 1):

`dpkg` print `un` (unknown) because its database isn't updated. You can use the `sync-available` from `dctrl-tools` package to synchronize `dpkg` info with `apt`.

```
sudo apt install dctrl-tools
sudo sync-available
```

[`man sync-available`](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/dctrl-tools/sync-available.8.en.html) :

```
 sync-available - sync dpkg's available database with apt's database 

DESCRIPTION
This program updates the dpkg(8) available database with the data in the apt(8)
package database. This is required for grep-available(1) and other similar
programs to give up-to-date results.
```